# ffmpeg version is 4.2.2. I'm trying to use h264_v4l2m2m encoder on tda4vm. Can anyone suggest me how can I fix the below issue

Tags: ffmpeg

> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set number of B-frames
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set number of B-frames
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set timeperframeFailed to set header mode
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set bit rate
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set gop size
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] h264 profile not found
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Encoder adjusted: qmin (0), qmax (51)
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set minimum video quantizer scale
> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x3d73a570] Failed to set maximum video quantizer scale

Comment: I tried below command, ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i 1080p_nv12_images_5num.yuv -c:v h264_v4l2m2m output.mp4

Comment: Hello, please don't include such important info in comments, edit it into your question, which is currently closable for "lack of details" IMO.